# Send data from bpm workflow to openERP?

Tags: jakarta-ee, odoo, xml-rpc, bonita, business-process-management

After a lot of research, i couldn't find any useful information that could be of use onto my problem.
My problem is how i can send business data from BPMS (bonita, tibgo, bizagi ....) to openERP via web services?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send data from Bonita BPM workflow (sorry I'm only familiar with this solution) to any external system you can use "connectors".
Bonita BPM provide a SOAP 1.2 Web Service connector that should allow you to push your process data to openERP.

You can refer to the [Web Service connector tutorial](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/web-service-connector-tutorial) form more information about the actual configuration of the connector.